# Point my one of my subdomain to my another website

Tags: web-hosting, dns, subdomain

I have a website say `somesite.com` which i want to be accessible via `some.mainsite.com`. I want it to be transparent for the visitors, so that they never know it is coming from `somesite.com`

I welcome answers without following constraints equally.

However in my case the `mainsite.com` is hosted on a windows server. And `somesite.com` is on a linux hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a `CNAME` namely `some` to the domain `mainsite.com` pointing to `somesite.com`.

   *This will forward all requests made to `some.mainsite.com` towards `somesite.com`.*
2. Add a `serverAlias` namely `some.mainsite.com` on `somesite.com`. This is also known as `parking` of domains (e.g. on [cPanel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel)).

   *This will tell your `somesite.com` host to accept all incoming request to `some.mainsite.com` and treat it as an alias to `somesite.com`.*

---

Both the sending and accepting parts are necessary, absence of either won't make any sense.

Comment: If you want to hide the somesite.com from the visitors aware of domain name system, you could use an A record instead of CNAME. Otherwise this is a suitable solution.